# Forward Outlook email

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I have these lines running to create a new email in Outlook. They are working well.

Now I want to make them work when I forwarded an email (instead of creating a new email) and also include the original email when I forwarded it.

How can I do that? Seems there’s only Application.CreateItem Method (Outlook) and no ForwardItem? Thank you.

```
Sub CreateMsg0()
Dim objMsg As MailItem

Set objMsg = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)

 With objMsg
  .To = "Alias@domain.com; Alias111@domain.com; Alias222@domain.com"
  .CC = "Alias2@domain.com"
  .Subject = "This is the subject"

  .HTMLBody = "<p style='color:rgb(0,51,102);font-family:calibri;font-size:18'>" & ep _
              & "Hello," & "<br>" & "<br>" & "<br>" & ep _
              & "Email body writing line number 1." & "<br>" & ep _
              & "Email body writing line number 2." & "<br>" & ep _
              & "</p>" & ep _
              & "<br>" & "<br>" & "<br>" & ep _
              & "<p style='color:rgb(0,51,102);font-family:calibri;font-size:15'>" & ep _
              & "Signature line 1." & "<br>" & ep _
              & "Tel./fax." & "<br>" & ep _
              & "</p>"


  .Display

End With

Set objMsg = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: You don't want to create a new MailItem. You want to get a handle on an existing mail item and `.Forward` it.  [Check this question out for possible example code.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28840066/forward-email-with-its-attachment-in-outlook-2010)

Comment: @GMan80013, thank you for the guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*What is **`ep _`** ? any way it should be Example*

```
Option Explicit
Sub CreateMsg0()
    Dim objMsg As mailitem
    Dim Item As Outlook.mailitem

    Set Item = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)

    Set objMsg = Item.Forward

    With objMsg
        .To = "Alias@domain.com; Alias111@domain.com; Alias222@domain.com"
        .CC = "Alias2@domain.com"
        .Subject = Item.Subject

        .HTMLBody = "<p style='color:rgb(0,51,102);font-family:calibri;font-size:18'>" _
                & "Hello," & "<br>" & "<br>" & "<br>" _
                & "Email body writing line number 1." & "<br>" _
                & "Email body writing line number 2." & "<br>" _
                & "</p>" _
                & "<br>" & "<br>" & "<br>" _
                & "<p style='color:rgb(0,51,102);font-family:calibri;font-size:15'>" _
                & "Signature line 1." & "<br>" _
                & "Tel./fax." & "<br>" _
                & "</p>" & "<BR>" & Item.HTMLBody

        .Display
    End With

    Set objMsg = Nothing
End Sub
```

---

*For the Subject = **`.Subject = Item.Subject`** & Body **`& Item.HTMLBody`***

*If you need the Recipients from original email then example would be*

```
With objMsg
    .To = Item.To
    .CC = Item.CC
    .Subject = Item.Subject
```

*[MSDN MailItem.Forward Method (Outlook)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-forward-method-outlook)*

Comment: very good! but it seems missed appended the "From:..Sent:...To:...Subject:..."  parts of the original email?

Comment: @MarkK Sorry I'm confused :-), you mean `Item.ReplyAll` https://stackoverflow.com/a/42805249/4539709 this?

Comment: thank you for the follow-up. I meant the first 4 lines (called header?) when people forwarded an email. the 4 lines are normally "From:..Sent:...To:...Subject:...". Is it because the line "...oMail.HTMLBody.."  shall be "...& vbCrLf & oMail.HTMLBody..." etc?